# ieeeaccess in overleaf epstopdf is not working?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, overleaf, epstopdf, ieeeaccess

I include this package at `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}`

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
```

but it still give
`Package pdftex.def Error: File 'filename.pdf' not found: using draft setting.`
I am using overleaf

Comment: you shouldn't need `epstopdf` or `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{`  also show a small complete document. for example you are not showing how you are calling `\includegraphics`  which or any extension are you using?

Comment: Here is code for figure. 

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{y.eps} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{x.eps} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by spaces in the file name. Removing spaces from the file name will resolve this problem.

Comment: I don't see a space in `filename.pdf`, which is the only filename in your question (and also not in `y.eps` or `x.eps`, the filenames in your comment to the question). So you are using information for this answer, that cannot be found in the question.